# How to add an automatically updated date without time to MS Project printout?

Tags: ms-project

When creating a print of task list in MS Project (v16), I set in the print menu under Page Setup the footer to `&[Date]`.
In the printout the date always contains the exact time (e.g. `Thu 12/11/20 15:00`) of the print as well. There is the predefined codeword `&[Time]` as well and it prints the time only, but how can I get a date without a time?
In the example above I would like to see `Thu 12/11/20` or something similar.

Right now my only solution is to edit the footer and enter the current date manually. I hope there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The format of &[Date] is set by your date format selection in Options.  Choose a date format there that has no time.  Unfortunately, this does not cover the case where you want the time to show on the task table but want it omitted from the legend.

Comment: That solves the initial problem. I could not spot unwanted side effects and the times within the task list remained visible (e.g. for Start, Finish, or Deadline).
Where exactly in the task list would I see an effect?

Comment: Interesting.... The formats of all dates in my task list automatically adopt the format setting (without time) immediately when the options are closed.  Apparently yours do not.  Which language pack are you on?